# How to Show and Hide HTML Form based on Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a piece of code in Javascript/Jquery to show and hide html form based on Radio button so that it can work in iPhone/iPad as well.

Here is what I am expecting.

```
Choice:
Pickup (Radio Button)
Delivery (Radio Button)
```

Based on the choice above

```
If it is Pickup.

Display a HTML FORM with few inputs to show the address of the place where items are being picked up.

If it is Delivery

Display a HTML Form with few inputs to accept delivery address.

and submit the data.
```

Any suggestions..?

I have tried the following with select box rather than radio box.

```
<pre>

    <!doctype html>
    <head>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#state").change(function() {
                    // foo is the id of the other select box 
                    if ($(this).val() != "Pickup") {
                        $("#foo").show();
                    }else{
                        $("#foo").hide();
                    } 
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>


    <body>
    <h3> Select Pickup Or Delivery:</h3>
        <p>
            <select id="state" name="state" style="width: 212px;">
                <option value="Pickup">Pickup</option>
                <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p id="foo" style="display:none;">

    <h4> Pickup Location:</h4>
            123 Main St, Edison NJ
        </p>
        <p id="foo" style="display:none;">
            <form>
    <h3> Enter your address below:</h3>
    <label>Address1</label> <input type="text" name="address1"><br>
    <label>Address2</label> <input type="text" name="address2"><br>
    <label>City</label>     <input type="text" name="city"><br>
    <label>State</label>    <input type="text" name="state"><br>
    <label>Zip Code</label> <input type="text" name="zipcode"><br>
        </p>
    </body>

</pre>
```

Comment: Here's what we're expecting: 1. JavaScript code you've got so far. 2. Why did it fail. 3. What other options you've tried. 4. A live demo.

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is your html is invalid. `H` tags can't be a child of `<p>` so browser renders them outside of the `<p>` and leaves `<p>` empty which is why you are not seeing the content hidden

Also you can't duplicate ID's in a page, use class instead. ID by definition is unique

Changing the `<P>` tags with invalid children to `<div>` and adjusting ID makes code work

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/a2Uh6/